# using javascript with help of jquery

Tags: jquery, django

Code written by me based on previous suggestions as follows .

Any help to efficinetly use jquery in order to make this code work .
Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function()  
     {
              self.setInterval("clock()",1000);  
              $("button").click(function()  
              {  
                     clock;  
              });  
              function clock()  
              {
                   clock();  
                   time=new Date();  
                   var s = "<p>" + time + "</p>";  
                   $(s).appendTo("div");  
              }  
     });  

<button > Click Me button  </div>
<div id="someid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("button").click(function()` should be either `$("#button").click(function()` or `$(".button").click(function()` depending on whether you are using the id or the class name.

if you are attaching to all buttons then `$("input:button").click(function()` will work I think.

Also what is `$(s).appendTo("div");` meant to be doing?

Need more info on what is not working and what you want to achieve.

**edit**

```
$(s).appendTo("div");
```

should be `$('#someid').append(s);` I think or `$(s).appendTo('#someid');`